# mysql: efficient way for postfix-search (like '%text' aka. prefix wildcard)?

Tags: mysql, wildcard

Is there any build-in functionality in MySQL to do the above without scanning the entire table?

Only solution I found is to store a mirrored version of the column I want to compare and do a `like 'txet%'`.

I also don't see a way of getting around the postfix-search. It is for a German dictionary. Many words have a version with prefix, e.g. the user searches for "Gericht" (Engl. curt), but it is also valuable to know that there is a word "Amtsgericht" (Engl. district curt). Unfortunately often there is no space separating the two parts of the word in German language. Approx 15% of queries actually use the prefix-search.

Comment: have a look at `mysql sphinx engine` or at `apache solr`

Comment: Thanks for the hint to sphinx! This could solve some other challenges I'm facing e.g. stemming. For the problem of this post I will use the reversed column approach as confirmed by the other answers. It will be the quickest solution, and the one with the least dependencies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A index over reverse field will be the solution, some think like:

```
create index idx_reverse on table ( reverse( field ) );
select * from table where reverse(field) like 'txet%';
```

but MySQL don't alow index over expressions, only over columns:

this is [MySQL create index syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html):

```
CREATE [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [index_option] ...
```

This is [postgres create index syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createindex.html):

```
CREATE [ UNIQUE ] INDEX [ CONCURRENTLY ] name ON table [ USING method ]
    ( { column | ( expression ) } [ opclass ] [, ...] )
    ...
```

A **work around** may be create indexed second field (field -> dleif) and a [mysql trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html) to keep reversed field:

```
alter table my_table add column dleif ...;
create index idx_reverse on my_table ( dleif );
Create Trigger `reverse_field` Before Update on `my_table` for each row BEGIN
    set new.dleif = reverse( new.field );
END;
select * from table where dleif like reverse('%text');
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL won't use an index when your value starts with a wildcard character.

Storing a second column in reverse order is a defensible approach. It will fail on a suffix, though.

If you know the compounded words, you can pre-compute "valuable to know" matches and store them in another table. I think that's unlikely to work well for a German dictionary, but you might know something I don't.

Comment: Thanks for the idea with the compounded words. I think this would be useful for infix search (like '%text%'). But since I am doing either prefix or postfix but not infix, the reversed column approach is what I will do. Also, although I am a German native it would require some research on grammar first and I have the suspicion, that the possibilities of building compound in German language are endless and thus would require huge amounts of data.

Comment: I used to live in Germany. My impression is that you can make a valid compound word out of any 'n' German words. And there's no upper limit on 'n'.

Comment: Yes that is true. A classic example: Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaft. It consists of the five nouns Donau, Dampf, Schiff, Fahrt, and Gesellschaft...:)