# Is there any way to make queries using functions in their WHERE sections relatively fast?

Tags: mysql

Let's take a table Companies with columns id, name and UCId. I'm trying to find companies whose numeric portion of the UCId matches some string of digits.

The UCIds usually look like XY123456 but they're user inputs and the users seem to really love leaving random spaces in them and sometimes even not entering the XY at all, and they want to keep it that way. What I'm saying is that I can't enforce a standard pattern. They want to enter it their way, and read it their way as well. So i'm stuck having to use functions in my where section.

Is there a way to make these queries not take unusably long in mysql? I know what functions to use and all that, I just need a way to make the search at least relatively fast. Can I somehow create a custom index with the functions already applied to the UCId?

just for reference an example of the query I'd like to use

```
SELECT * 
FROM Companies 
WHERE digits_only(UCId) = 'some_digits.'
```

I'll just add that the Companies tables usually has tens of thousands of rows and in some instances the query needs to be run repeatedly, that's why I need a fast solution.

Comment: MySQL don't allow expressions in index, see my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456272/mysql-efficient-way-for-postfix-search-like-text-aka-prefix-wildcard

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's very useful.

Comment: not sure if that is possible with mysql, but i know from other databases that you can add an index to say digits_only(UCId).

Comment: @Bogdan, glad to hear that is useful, in this case vote it up ;)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have such things as function- (generally speaking, expression-) based indexes (like in [Oracle](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes.php) or [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/indexes-expressional.html)). One possible workaround is to add another column to `Companies` table, which will actually be filled by normalized values (i.e., `digits_only(UCId)`). This column can be managed in your code or via DB triggers set on INSERT/UPDATE.

Comment: ugh, fridays. Should've thought of this before spamming the internet with what is now obvious to be a highschool level question. Thanks, will probably do exactly this.